# How do you get the key of a node that is added to the diagram in GoJS?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I would like to get the key info when a node gets dropped from the palette to the diagram (similar to the memberAdded property in the group class). I am assuming it's the ExternalObjectsDropped event handler but when I check e.subject.part, the output is undefined. Am I missing something or doing it wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(go.Diagram, . . .,
  {
    "ExternalObjectsDropped": function(e) {
      // e.subject is a go.Set of the dropped Parts
      e.subject.each(function(p) {
        if (p instanceof go.Node) console.log(p.key);
      })
    }
  })
```

More info at: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/events.html#ExternalObjectsDropped